# Let $f,g : X\to X$ be real continuous functions such that $f(X)\cap g(X) = \emptyset$ and $f(X)\cup g(X) = X$. Which sets cannot be equal to $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f,g : X\rightarrow X$ be continuous functions such that $f(X)\cap g(X) = \emptyset$ and $f(X)\cup g(X) = X$.

Which one of the following sets cannot be equal to $X$ ?

A. $[0, 1]$

B. $(0, 1)$

C. $[0, 1)$

D. $\mathbb{R}$

Please explain all options.

My approach:

Simply we can see the conditions imply that $X$ is disconnected. Continuity implies that $f([0,1])$ and $g([0,1])$ are compact. From the above conditions. Compact set would not be connected so $X\ne [0,1]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ were compact, so would $f[X]$ and $g[X]$ be, and they'd be two closed disjoint non-empty subsets of $X$ that form a partition of $X$, so then $X$ is not connected.

So we know a compact $X$ cannot be connected.

Comment: I know image of compact set is compact and [0,1] is compact and so f[0,1] and g[0,1] if they were disjoint then satisfies the condition. But option a) is false given

Comment: Henno@ explain all options I have mentioned  it.

Comment: @JohnNash There is only one right answer I suppose, and now you've identified  it.

Comment: @JohnNash You know for sure that the option A is right: $X$ cannot be $[0,1]$, $X$ **can** be $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$, but you have to come up with examples for that (just draw pictures). BCD are wrong.

Comment: @JohnNash B and D are homeomorphic, so an example for one can be turned into an example for the other. For $[0,1)$ it's easy: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x$ and $g(x) =   \frac{1}{2}(x+1)$ will do, I think.

Comment: @JohnNash A is definitely right. Your answer key also says so. I said so. There is no discrepancy.

Comment: means $X$ may be $[0,1]$

Comment: @JohnNash yes, because the conditions (existence of $f,g$) imply that **if** $X$ is compact **then** $X$ is disconnected. $[0,1]$ is compact **and** connected. So $X$ **cannot** be $[0,1]$ as claimed by A.

Comment: what can you say about other options mean b and c

Comment: @JohnNash I gave an example that $X=[0,1)$ is possible in an earlier comment. For $\mathbb{R}$, take any $f$ that has image $[0,\infty)$, like $f(x)=x^2$, and one with image $(-\infty,0)$, like $g(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+1}$. Similar ideas work for $(0,1)$ too.